# Hiding parameters un url with nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I have a website with this kind of adresses:

```
www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/[userprofile1]?r=[login]&w=[encryptedpassword]
```

ie:

```
www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/toto?r=reqqfdvca&w=skvlsqmg 
www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/titi?r=re45a&w=slkvldfgmg 
www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/tutu?r=reqq0krgca&w=s46893ls
```

etc...

the parameters are important because there are credentials to access the website but I would like my adresses to look like:

```
www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/toto
www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/titi
www.mydomain.com/user/userprofile/tutu
```

etc...

I'm new with nginx, and my english is not perfect so please excuse my mistakes, but does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

thanks

Comment: You want to do an "URL rewriting", search with this word you'll find your answer

Comment: Yes that's it, but I'm not familiar with regex and I'm not sure wich one I'm suppose to use :-/

Comment: So i can just advise you to learn how regex work (it's not that much hard) and the do you URL rewriting .. Make some test with some fake pages, or change your git branch ..

Comment: @bpollet If you want to move credentials off the URL, you probably need to start using cookies.